# My Dell Inspiron N5050 Won't connect to any Wireless

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dell-inspiron, wireless-adapter

I have a brand new DELL Inspiron which used to connect to my WiFI. I had the laptop off for about 2 months and when I turned it on it will not connect to my Wireless with WPA2+AES encryption. All of my other devices (iPad, Laptops, XBOX, Roku, etc) are able to connect without a problem. I also tried connecting to other opened WiFIs in my area and was unable to do so. I even tried connecting 2 feet away from the router without luck where the signal is excellent (so is everywhere else around the house).

Machine configuration:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Adapter is Dell Wireless 1702 802.11b/g/n
- Driver: Atheros Communications Inc, 4/21/2011, Version: 9.2.0.412

I tried:

- Deleting the driver from Device Manager and restarting
- Installing drivers from Dell, but it appears I have the latest version
- Tried to connect to an unsecured Virtual Interface (DD-WRT)
- Changed the Bandwidth on the adapter to 20MHz/40MHz Auto (my router is 40MHz
  channel width)

What could be causing the problem? What else can I try? What else can I provide to help troubleshoot this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your wifi is probably disabled on the machine.

First off, prove it by trying to connect with an Ethernet cable.

Lots of laptops have a light to show if wifi is on or not (near the keyboard)

Or, your typing the password in wrong. Make sure you have NumLock on.  If you look carefully, the keys U,I,O,J,K and L have some numbers in the same color of the Fn key, i.e, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2 and 3. This is your numeric keypad. 3) Hold pressed both the left Alt key and the Fn key, while you write the code with the numeric keypad. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am able to connect with an ethernet cable. The WIFI is on because I can see the list of WIFIs

Comment: Yes, I enter the correct password. It says "connecting" and then it comes up with the message: "Windows was unable to connect to [WIFIName]. Solve Problem." When I click on "Solve Problem" it opens up the "Windows Network Diagnostics Wizard", which doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Can you open command prompt (type cmd in the search box) and type ipconfig and see if it says media disconnected or not?

Comment: Yes, it says "Media Disconnected"

Comment: The only way I've ever solved this is with a system restore. Howver, from the command prompt please do both of these: *netsh winsock reset catalog*  ... next if using IPv4  *netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log*  ... or if using IPv6 *netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log*  .. then reboot

Comment: That did not do it. I'm now starting on Safe Mode with networking and see if it solves it

Comment: The command. I'm now trying Safe Mode with Networking and see what happens. If it doesn't work I will try system restore

Comment: A factory restore did not solve the problem. It seems that there might be an issue with the adapter.

Comment: Factory Restore did not solve the problem. It's weird, because if it was faulty how is it possible to even be able to find the WIFIs? I have a hunch that it might be a software issue, rather than hardware. What do you think?

Comment: Factory Restore from the hidden partition. Installing everything as day 1 and going through Dell's crapware installation process.

Comment: FN+F2 turns off the wireless antena.

Comment: Wow, I just plugged in an old G router and it connected without problem. It sounds like a compatibility issue

Comment: Furthermore, my router was setup to N only. I then switched to N/G mixed and it connects. According Device Manager it is a b/g/n router, so this doesn't make sense. It must be a driver issue!

Comment: for history sake I say we leave them as a way for people to find possible answers to their problems and add a new answer explaining what the issue was

Answer (score 0):

I was recently unable to connect an ipad to my home wifi. Everything else connected fine, but not this device.

Turned out the router LAN IP configuration had been set to allow a max number of 6 users. This device would have been the seventh, and so it wasn't allowed to connect. Once I increased this number, I no longer had any problems.

Comment: Interesting, could you [edit] your answer with the make and model of the router?